# Rudin functional analysis, theorem 3.23. Finite intersection property

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111322/rudins-functional-analysis-theorem-3-23-point-b).

Continuing through the proof there's a subtlety I don't get, but I think it would be educational to understand to improve my background in general topology.

> Choose some $S \in \mathcal{P}$. Let $\mathcal{P}'$ be the collection of all members of $\mathcal{P}$ that are subsets of $S$. Since $S \in \mathcal{P}'$, $\mathcal{P}'$ is not empty. Partially order $\mathcal{P}'$ by set inclusion, let $\Omega$ be a maximal totally ordered subcollection of $\mathcal{P}'$, and let $M$ be the intersection of all members of $\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is a collection of compact sets with the finite intersection property, $M \neq \emptyset$.

Now I'm referring to theorem in [this page](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/finite-intersection-property-criterion-for-compactness-in-a),

Is such theorem the one used implicitly by Rudin to assess the finite intersection property?

Also... the proof continues as

> The maximality of $\Omega$ implies that no proper subset of $M$ belongs to $\mathcal{P}$.

Not sure I get this bit as well... how exactly is maximality used to asses that no proper subset of $M$ doesn't belong to $\mathcal{P}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rudin uses [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma#Alternative_formulation) to prove the existence of $\Omega$.
- The finite intersection property is a known fact of compact sets X: [Any collection of closed subsets of X with the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Equivalent_definitions)

Comment: What about the consequence of the maximality of $\Omega$?

Comment: Huh? You wrote yourself  : > The maximality of $\Omega$ implies that no proper subset of $M$ belongs to $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: And then I wrote "how exactly is maximality used to asses..."

Comment: I mean $\Omega$ is a collection of compact extreme sets anyway, and $M$ is intersection of these, which is in $\mathcal{P}$ specifically. But why does maximality of $\Omega$ allow to say that no proper subset of $M$ is in $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: If there were a proper subset of $M$ in $P$,say $X$ then, as $\Omega$ is maximal it should include that $X$ as well. But then the intersection of all members of $\Omega$ is $X$ which is a contradiction to the definition of $M$. So, no proper subset can exist.

Comment: Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Rudin is very compact. I consulted my notes as well ;-)

Comment: Glad to know my questions aren't exactly "silly" then.