# Rudin functional analysis, theorem 3.23. Use of separation property.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces

Still following the theorem 3.23 (Krein-Milman), follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111415/rudin-functional-analysis-theorem-3-23-finite-intersection-property).

The proof again continues

> It now follows from (b) that every $\Lambda \in X^*$ is constant on $M$, since $X^*$ separates points on $X$, $M$ has only one point.

To get why $\Lambda$ is constant on $M$, I know from (b) that $M_{\Lambda}$ is in $\mathcal{P}$, which means is a compact extreme set, I don't understand why this might imply that $\Lambda$ is constant on $M$. My guess was using the definition of $M_\Lambda$, but I'm not sure how, and mainly the reason is since $\Lambda$ is in $X^*$ it can return a complex number in general, but the definition of $M_\Lambda$ would only use the real part of $\Lambda x$ not the imaginary.

Also the fact that $M$ contains only one point isn't clear to me.

Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know from (b) that $M_{\Lambda}$ is in $\mathcal{P}$.
If $\Lambda$ would not be constant on $M_{\Lambda}$, then either the real part of $\Lambda$ is not constant, or the imaginary part is not constant. Without loss of generality we may assume the real part of $\Lambda$ not to be constant, otherwise use $\Lambda:=-i\Lambda\in X^*$

So, if the real part of $\Lambda$ is not constant let us define $Q:=\{x\in M_{\Lambda}: Re \;\Lambda x = \max_{y\in M_{\Lambda}} Re \;\Lambda y\}$. If $\Lambda$ is not a constant then $Q$ is a proper subset of $M_{\Lambda}$ and therefore a proper subset of  $M$  - which is not possible by the design of $M$.

In case $M$ contains two different elements, then since $X^*$ separates points you can seperate the two elements with a continuous linear functional.
But this functional has to be constant on $M$ as we just proved above, which is a contradiction. So $M$ may just contain one element.

Comment: I need to put together all the pieces of your answer. You say that if $\Lambda$ isn't constant on $M_{\Lambda}$ then either the real part or the imaginary isn't constant. But $M_{\Lambda}$ is defined as the set of all values where the real part is constant (more specifically to the max value of the real part), therefore it might be the case that the imaginary part isn't constant. I'm not sure I get the explanation at this point.

Comment: Ok, in case only the imaginary part of $\Lambda$ is not constant in $M$, then we apply our argumentation to the linear funcional $-i\Lambda$ (where we now know that its real part is not constant) ... and conclude that  $-i\Lambda$'s real part must be constant, so $\Lambda$ must be constant.

Comment: Sorry but in your answer I struggle to distinguish if you're talking about $M_{\Lambda}$ or $M$, one is a subset of the other.

Comment: I assume $\Lambda := -i\Lambda$ is a mistake.

Comment: No, it should be read as replace $\Lambda$ by $-i\Lambda$ ( which turns the old imaginary part to be the new real part)

Comment: Ok, your answer seems a bit clearer now, I'll carefully read through it again.

Comment: On more question is your use of the Hahn-Banach theorem related to the fact that the $X^*$ separates points? The Hahn-Banach theorem doesn't require that.

Comment: Accepting your answer, but I think I'll bug you later with some question probably. Thank you so much.